# How  to  set Background  color  of  expandable  List  in android

Tags: android, background, expandablelistview

I have one expandable list view and i need to set background to Expandable list view.
How to set this background?

Answer (score 5):

You need to set both the background color AND the [cacheColorHint](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#attr_android:cacheColorHint) to the same color (black, in the example below).  If you don't, the list will appear to flicker as you scroll through it, same as a regular [ListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html).

```
<ExpandableListView
    android:background="#000000"
    android:cacheColorHint="#000000"
    ... />
```

Also, your child views will be drawn over the ExpandableListView, so make sure you aren't setting their background colors unnecessarily.